# Existence of filter bar, if data is not filterable

Tags: tables, filter, tabs

There is a page, displaying various information referring to one product. Information is divided into tabs - and within the tabs, user can filter data - but not always. Some tabs contain information that can not be filtered.

What is a better approach - to keep the filter bar for those tabs, which are not filterable? What to display inside the filter bar, then?

Or is it better to remove the filter bar (which gives a very bad feeling of "jumping" screen, but maybe is more proper anyway?).

[image: Filter bar on the left]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Is the task similar?

If the data (or task) is similar in both tabs than always show the filter bar. Your users might expect it and otherwise go look for it. In the filter bar you can explain that there are currently no filters possible. Additionally, this will keep the screen consistent while switching tab, which is desirable behavior.

#### Is the task different?

If there are large differences between tabs, such as different tasks or unrelated data set. You might want to consider placing the filter tab hierarchically **under** the tab. Meaning it is part of the tab 'details 2'. For example:

[image: Filter hierarchically under tab]
[image: Horizontal filtering options]